# Passing NODE_ENV to docker to run package.json scripts

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

This is my dockerfile :

```
FROM node:6-onbuild

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app

ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE ${PORT}

CMD [ "npm","run", "start" ]
```

and in package.json I do have this :

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node start.js",
  "stagestart": "NODE_ENV=content-staging node start.js"
}
```

the `start` script is for production, now I want a way to run the staging script in dockerfile. is there a way to read NODE_ENV inside dockerfile, so I can have one dockerfile which handle staging and production.

Comment: Seems like a bit of an ant-pattern for Docker. Also not quite clear if you want to run a different script or just a different environment variable, both of which you could do when creating the _container_.

Comment: @ldg I need to run different script actually, but not sure how should I run each one of them separately.

Comment: Creating two dockerfiles

Comment: You can only one package.json file at each node application so if you need different app start  then you need to start your application  from script. btw check my detailed answer if its not what you want you can comment.

Comment: You should not run commands through `npm`. This slows down processing by a good amount. Better use `node start.js` directly when in production.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is two possible implementation.

> FYI: you don't need to mention NODE_ENV  in package.json if you
>   already set NODE_ENV at the system level or set NODE_ENV during build time or runtime in docker.

Here `Dockerfile` as same but I used to `alpine` base image

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
ENV PORT 3000
ARG DOCKER_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=${DOCKER_ENV}
RUN if [ "$DOCKER_ENV" = "stag" ] ; then  echo   your NODE_ENV for stage is $NODE_ENV;  \
else  echo your NODE_ENV for dev is $NODE_ENV; \
fi 


EXPOSE ${PORT}

CMD [ "npm","run", "start" ]
```

when you build this Dockerfile with this command

```
docker build --build-arg DOCKER_ENV=stag -t test-node .
```

You will see at layer

```
 ---> Running in a6231eca4d0b your NODE_ENV for stage is stag
```

When you run this docker container and run this command your output will be

```
/usr/src/app # echo $NODE_ENV

stag
```

**Simplest Approch** same image and but set environment variable at run time

Your Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD [ "npm","run", "start" ]
```

Run this docker image with this command

```
docker build -t  test-node .

 docker run  --name test -e NODE_ENV=content-staging  -p 3000:3000 --rm -it test-node ash
```

So when you run this command at container you will see

```
/usr/src/app # echo $NODE_ENV
content-staging
```

So this is how you can start your node application with **NODE_ENV** without setting environment variable at package.json. So if your nodejs configuration is based on **NODE_ENV** it should pick configuration according to **NODE_ENV** .

Comment: you welcome but would you like to share they way you did @Emad

Comment: Well, I find another way, I used Buildkite and since I used ECS, in my ecs-task I defined my ENV variable, then it's no matter which script we run, "start" or "stagestart" it will send all ENV variables to buildkite. Basically I didn't change anything on my docker.

Comment: Oh, are you using  AWS ECS? you can define ENV in your task definition which is same as I mention docker start command. but if you define env in docker file ECS container will get from docker file too. But my solution how u can implement on local system.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it does not work for me. When I `console.log(process.env)` it echos `{ ... NODE_ENV: 'production' ... }`, but 1 line below `console.log(proces.env.NODE_ENV)` echos `development`. Can someone explain what is going on? I even tried [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) with `NODE_ENV=production` before the run command but it doesnt work either.

Comment: @Reijo Where you set environment variables?

Comment: Just like the first approach in your answer

Comment: this is strange that you see two value @Reijo, let run command inside container `echo $NODE_ENV` or `printenv`. try to print all `ENV` in system-level before processing in `nodejs`.  seems like some thing wrong in nodejs configuration

Comment: I will dig further when I got time for this. For now I worked around this with a command line argument and a config file. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ENV instruction to get the environment variable as an environment variable inside container. Have an entry point script that injects the available environment variable (perhaps something as simple as sed) in place of a placeholder variable name that is in your package.json file. Then start your node application. Obviously this will require you to make a few changes to your Dockerfile in regards to entrypoint script etc.

That is how I have achieved such things in the past.